# Button is not appearing/being able to be moved in the section I put it in

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my portfolio and my button is appearing in the about section(when I inspect element). In [my photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOg2C.png) the about section is overlapping with the home section(i think). Below is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="main.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>2024 port</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <nav id="mainNav">
    <div id="Navbar">
        
    <a href="#Home">Home</a>
    <a href="#About">About</a>
    <a href="#Work">Work</a>
    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    </nav>


    <section href="Home" id="Home">
        <h1 class="introduction">Hey, my name is 
            <span class="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r">William</span>
        </h1>
        
        <button onclick="window.location.href='#Work'" class="btn-shimmer">view my work</button>








    </section>


    <section href="About" id="About"><h1></h1></section>
    <section href="Work" id="Work"><h1>Work</h1></section>
    <section href="Contact" id="Contact"><h1>Contact</h1></section>
















    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS CODE

```
    /* MAIN */
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

        body{
            background-image: 
            linear-gradient(to right, #242424, transparent 1px),
            linear-gradient(to bottom, #252525, transparent 1px);
            background-size: 30px 30px;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
            font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        }


        section {
            height: 100vh;
            
        }

        #Home,
        #About,
        #Work,
        #Contact {
            color: white;
           
        }

        /* NAVBAR */

        @keyframes glow {
            0% {
                box-shadow: -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 
                            2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            }
            50% {
                box-shadow:2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 
                -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            }
            100% {
                box-shadow: -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 
                            2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            }
        }

        nav{
            /* background-color: #202020; */
            text-align: center;
            background: #242424;
            border: #242424 80px;
            border-radius: 50px;    
            width: fit-content;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px; 
            
            box-shadow: 

              -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 
               2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);

               animation: glow 2s infinite alternate;

        }
   
     
        

        a{
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-right: 8px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 600;
            text-size-adjust: 350px;
        }


        .sticky {
            position: sticky;
            text-align: center;
            background: #242424;
            top: 8px;
            border-radius: 50px;    
            width: fit-content;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-right: 10px; 
            z-index: 1000;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        #Navbar{
            text-size-adjust: 100px;


        }
        
        a:hover{
        color: #3F88C5;


        }

        .text-transparent {
            color: transparent;
        }
        
        .bg-clip-text {
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
        }
        
        .bg-gradient-to-r {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #3b82f6, #ec4899, #3b82f6); 
        }
        

    
        /* HOME/LANDING PAGE */
        #Home {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .introduction{

            text-align: left;
            padding-right: 400px;
            padding-left: 100px;
            font-size: 150px;
            padding-bottom: 400px;

        }

        .btn-shimmer {
            display: inline-flex;
            height: 3rem; 
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            border-radius: 0.375rem; 
            border: 1px solid #4b5563; 
            background-image: linear-gradient(110deg, #000103, 45%, #1e2631, 55%, #000103);
            background-size: 200% 100%;
            padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem; 
            font-weight: 500; 
            color: #cbd5e0;
            transition: color 0.2s ease, background-position 2s linear; 
            outline: none;
            animation: shimmer 2s linear infinite; 
            height: fit-content;
          }
          
          @keyframes shimmer {
            0% {
              background-position: 0 0;
            }
            100% {
              background-position: -200% 0;
            }
          }
          
          .btn-shimmer:hover {
            color: #ffffff; 
          }
          
          .btn-shimmer:focus {
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(66, 153, 225, 0.5); 
          }
```

Couldn't find anything that would be overlapping in CSS. Haven't done anything website related in a while and this is my first project back.

Answer (score 0):

Your About section's h1 tag is blank, if you put something in it then it will show up.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

body {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to right, #242424, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, #252525, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}


section {
    height: 100vh;
}

#Home,
#About,
#Work,
#Contact {
    color: white;

}

/* NAVBAR */

@keyframes glow {
    0% {
        box-shadow: -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
            2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }

    50% {
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
            -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }

    100% {
        box-shadow: -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
            2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
}

nav {
    /* background-color: #202020; */
    text-align: center;
    background: #242424;
    border: #242424 80px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: fit-content;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;

    box-shadow:

        -2px -1px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
        2px 3px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);

    animation: glow 2s infinite alternate;

}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-size-adjust: 350px;
}


.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    text-align: center;
    background: #242424;
    top: 8px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: fit-content;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#Navbar {
    text-size-adjust: 100px;


}

a:hover {
    color: #3F88C5;


}

.text-transparent {
    color: transparent;
}

.bg-clip-text {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}

.bg-gradient-to-r {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #3b82f6, #ec4899, #3b82f6);
}


/* HOME/LANDING PAGE */
#Home {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.introduction {

    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 400px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    font-size: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 400px;

}

.btn-shimmer {
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 3rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    border: 1px solid #4b5563;
    background-image: linear-gradient(110deg, #000103, 45%, #1e2631, 55%, #000103);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #cbd5e0;
    transition: color 0.2s ease, background-position 2s linear;
    outline: none;
    animation: shimmer 2s linear infinite;
    height: fit-content;
}

@keyframes shimmer {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: -200% 0;
    }
}

.btn-shimmer:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.btn-shimmer:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(66, 153, 225, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainNav">
   <div id="Navbar">
      <a href="#Home">Home</a>
      <a href="#About">About</a>
      <a href="#Work">Work</a>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
   </div>
</nav>
<section href="Home" id="Home">
   <h1 class="introduction">Hey, my name is 
      <span class="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r">William</span>
   </h1>
   <button onclick="window.location.href='#Work'" class="btn-shimmer">view my work</button>
</section>
<section href="About" id="About">
   <h1>About</h1>
</section>
<section href="Work" id="Work">
   <h1>Work</h1>
</section>
<section href="Contact" id="Contact">
   <h1>Contact</h1>
</section>
```